# How to restreint access to rpc?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I want to restreint access to my ethereum node (geth) via rpc interface for some machines, 
for example : localhost and 10.x.x.x

how to deal with that?

Comment: It is a bad idea to expose your rpc server online, be carefull !!!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to restrict outbound as well as inbound connections.
There is parameter `allow-ips` for filtering outbound connections in `parity`, not sure about `geth`

`--allow-ips FILTER               Filter outbound connections.`

It can help partially, but I think it would be better to do it on OS level.

- Windows - firewall.
- Linux - https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables
- Azure VM - NAT